# MultiThreading In Java: Print multiplication table from 1 to 10 each thread should print one table

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to understand the `multithreading` in `java`and I am trying to execute a program that will print multiplication table from 1 to 100 and each thread should print one table.

```
public class Test2 implements Runnable  {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    final Test2 testThr = new Test2();

    for(int i =1; i<=100; i++){
        Thread t1=new Thread(testThr);
        t1.start();
    }

}

@Override
public void run() {
    for(int i=1; 1<=10; i++) {
        sync(i);
    }
}

public synchronized void sync(int num){
    for (int i=1;i<=10;i++){
        System.out.println(i + "X" + num + ": "  +i*num  +Thread.currentThread().getName());
        try{
            Thread.sleep(500);
        }catch (Exception e) {}
    }
}
```

}

**output I am getting:**

```
1X1: 1Thread-0
2X1: 2Thread-0
3X1: 3Thread-0
4X1: 4Thread-0
5X1: 5Thread-0
1X1: 1Thread-4
2X1: 2Thread-4
3X1: 3Thread-4
4X1: 4Thread-4
5X1: 5Thread-4
1X1: 1Thread-3
2X1: 2Thread-3
3X1: 3Thread-3
4X1: 4Thread-3
5X1: 5Thread-3
1X2: 2Thread-3
2X2: 4Thread-3
3X2: 6Thread-3
4X2: 8Thread-3
5X2: 10Thread-3
1X3: 3Thread-3
2X3: 6Thread-3
3X3: 9Thread-3
4X3: 12Thread-3
......
```

**I want to print multiplication table from 1 to 100 but the point is I want 1 table should print by anyone of the thread.Suppose Multiplication table of 5 get print by thread-1(or any other thread), table of 1 get print by thread-3.**

**output I want:**

```
1X1: 1 Thread-3
1X2: 2 Thread-3
1X3: 3 Thread-3
1X4: 4 Thread-3
.....
1X10: 10 Thread-3
3X1:3 Thread-10
3X2:6 Thread-10
3X3:9 Thread-10
........
3X10:30 Thread-10
```

If any thread starts printing the table of any number then it should print the complete table(upto 10) other should wait for its completion.

Comment: @matt, I updated the question a little but all I want is to print multiplication table from 1 to 100 and want 1 table should get print by 1 thread.

Comment: The problem is you have a completely serial task. Your task is in no way parallel. You iterate over 10 values and print them. They cannot be run it out of order, so each thread has to wait for the other to complete. I think the answer that uses join demonstrates how ridiculous your task is.

Answer (score 0):

You must join your thread execution if you want to execute a complete Thread before the next one. Also I suggest you to implements Runnable instead of extend the class Thread.

```java
class Multithreading implements Runnable
{
    int num;

    Multithreading(int num){
        this.num = num;
    }

    synchronized public void printTable()  {
        int n = this.num;
        for (int i = 1; i<=10; i++){
            System.out.println(i +"X"+n+": "+ i*n+ Thread.currentThread().getName());
            try{
                Thread.sleep(500);
            }catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        printTable();
    }

}
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int n = 100;

        for(int i = 1; i<=n; i++) {

            Thread t = new Thread(new Multithreading(i));
            t.start();
            t.join();
        }
    }
}
```

Here and example of the output result

```
1X1: 1Thread-2
2X1: 2Thread-2
3X1: 3Thread-2
4X1: 4Thread-2
5X1: 5Thread-2
6X1: 6Thread-2
7X1: 7Thread-2
8X1: 8Thread-2
9X1: 9Thread-2
10X1: 10Thread-2
1X2: 2Thread-4
2X2: 4Thread-4
3X2: 6Thread-4
4X2: 8Thread-4
```

Comment: No, in the loop ```java for(int i = 1; i<=n; i++) {

            Thread t = new Thread(new Multithreading(i));
            t.start();
            t.join();
        } ```you create a thread in each iteration

Comment: Right, but t.start() then t.join() just says start a thread and wait for it to finish. There is very little difference between that and single threaded.

Answer (score 0):

Well I tried this code and now it is working as I was expecting.

```
class Multithread implements Runnable {

    final int num;
    Multithread(int num) {
        this.num = num;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        Test2.sync(this.num);

    }
}

public class Test2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for(int i =1; i<=5; i++){
            Multithread mt = new Multithread(i);
            Thread t1=new Thread(mt);
            t1.start();
        }

    }

    public static synchronized void sync(int num){
        for (int i=1;i<=5;i++){
            System.out.println(num + "X" + i + ": "  +i*num  +Thread.currentThread().getName());
            try{
                Thread.sleep(500);
            }catch (Exception e) {}
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Since your using a static method the synchronization is on the class Test2 which means only one thread will enter that method at the same time. There is no guarantee about which "mt" will run first or next. So if you wanted to print first the ones table, then the twos etc etc. You will not always get that order. This is horrible practice.